# vb.net remove private method from listening to button click event in a private control

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have this FindButton_Click method in a private Control which is causing a crash. I have added a new method to handle the click event. I want to stop  this FindButton_Click method from getting called using reflection. could you please enlighten me on this, if it is possible to remove?

This is how the default method is added to the event in a private overridable set property.

```
Dim handler As EventHandler = New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.FindButton_Click)
If (Not Me._mobjFindButton Is Nothing) Then
      RemoveHandler Me._mobjFindButton.Click, handler
End If
If (Not Me._mobjFindButton Is Nothing) Then
    AddHandler Me._mobjFindButton.Click, handler
End If
```

Comment: You say that this is how the default method is *added* to the event, but the code uses `RemoveHandler`. Is that a correct copy of your code?

Comment: oh I missed the last line, this is the full code. It is first removed and then added again whenever a set property is called.

Comment: That makes more sense. Not sure what you're wanting to accomplish. Is the old function being called by reflection and you want to block that? Or do you want to use reflection to stop this FindButton_Click method from being called? The question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I want to use reflection to stop this FindButton_Click method from being called.The below code fails to compile at the (AddressOf lOOTBFindBtnClickInfo.Name) line as this method is not in my code . I could not get to pass the address of a private method to create evenhandler below.
      Dim lOOTBFindBtnClickInfo As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = GetType(SPFBaseRelQueryCtrl).GetMethod("FindButton_Click", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
     
       Dim handler As EventHandler = New EventHandler(AddressOf lOOTBFindBtnClickInfo.Name)
           RemoveHandler mobjFindButton.Click, handler